# Linux: How to change the extension of a bunch of files?

Tags: linux, scripting, shell

I have a directory full of files ending with .xxx.  (`Apple.xxx`, `Orange.xxx`, `Bannana.xxx`)

I want to change their extensions to .yyy.  (`Apple.yyy`, `Orange.yyy`, `Bannana.yyy`)

What's the quickest way to accomplish this using basic shell commands?

Comment: Much the same question and answers at http://superuser.com/questions/8716/rename-a-group-of-files-with-one-command/8723

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at the rename command: `rename .xxx .yyy *.xxx`

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks for introducing me to the rename command.

Comment: Rename is good too :-)

Comment: On debian varieties, rename actually accepts a regular expression, which allows you do some pretty powerful renaming.

Comment: On Fedora, the rename command is included in the *util-linux-ng* package.

Answer (score 7):

```
 for i in *.xxx; do 
     mv "$i" "${i%.*}.yyy"
 done
```

The percent sign in "${i%.*}" means use the *glob* pattern that is after the percent sign, apply it to the value of the variable i, and remove the shortest possible match from the tail end of that value.  This called Parameter / Variable expansion, and has many uses.  You can also make it so the glob is longest possible match or make the glob match from the start as well.  [This Linux Journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-parameter-expansion) is all about parameter expansion.

It is put in double quotes so that if there are spaces in the filename and the IFS variable is set to include spaces (the norm), the filename will still be passed to mv as one argument.

Answer (score 3):

Install [mmv](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/mmv) and then do this:

```
mmv -r "*.xxx" "#1.yyy"
```

Comment: mmv can also change all filenames in lowercase:

    mmv "*" "#l1"

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this command. It's the first time I've heard about it and it's included in Fedora, too (the *mmv* package).

Answer (score 1):

Already a bunch of answers, but I'll add my own.

```
for i in *.xxx; do
    mv "$i" "`basename $i .xxx`.yyy"
done
```

Comment: Basename is probably not builtin to the shell ( to see, use the 'which basename' ).  So it might be a touch slower, it is however, a lot easier to read and remember :-)  So you get my upvote.

Comment: You have an error syntax in `for $i ...`. It should be `for i...`. Even after correcting this, the script fails if the file names contain multiple spaces, e.g. `c  d.xxx` [you're seeing only 1 space because of formatting limitations]. To fix this error, you need to put the `$i` parameter of basename inside quotes.