# How to cut extension from pathname with basic unix tools

Tags: linux, bash

I need to gather a list of files and put this in a textfile. However, the files should not include their extension.

The command I have now without removing file extensions:

```
ls -1 /a/dir/*/dir/* > textfile
```

All selected files will have a an extension of .[a-z]{3}

(the reason I need this is because I need a list of unique base names, and `unique` will solve that after this step)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always like to include a bash only solution:

```
for file in /a/dir/*/dir/*; do
    echo "${file%.*}" >> ~/file_list
done
```

and with an optional if statement to limit the file to your requested extension:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in /a/dir/*/dir/*; do
    if [[ "$file" =~ \.[a-zA-Z]{3}$ ]]; then
        echo "${file%.*}" >> ~/file_list
    fi
done
```

In [this similar serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/44854/linux-how-to-change-the-extension-of-a-bunch-of-files) question I explain the "${file%.*}" parameter expansion.

Answer (score 5):

Something like that would list the file in the current directory removing everything after the first dot.

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -iZ basename Z | cut -d"." -f1 > /tmp/resultfile`

It would eventually have an issue with hidden files resulting in a blank line in the result file. Basename is here only to get rid of the "./" begining the filenames in the *find* result.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
ls -1 /a/dir/*/dir/* | sed -e 's/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\{3\}$//'
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: I disagree with the edit, but cannot reject as I don't have enough points.  The original question explicitly states that the pattern being matched is .[a-z]{3}, so the edit to add [A-Z] is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

It's much more simple than one thinks:

```
asd@locutus:~$ IZE=file.avi
asd@locutus:~$ echo $IZE
file.avi
asd@locutus:~$ echo ${IZE%%.???}
file
asd@locutus:~$
```

So in this manner:

```
ls -1 /a/dir/*/dir/* | while read VAR; do echo ${VAR%.???}; done
```

You can do whatever you want between do and done, echo is just an example.

man bash (Parameter Expansion):

```
   ${parameter%%word}
          The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname  expansion.
          If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of param‐
          eter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter
          with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘‘%’’ case) or the longest match‐
          ing pattern (the ‘‘%%’’ case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the  pat‐
          tern  removal  operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn,
          and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array  vari‐
          able subscripted with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to
          each member of the array in turn, and  the  expansion  is  the  resultant
          list.
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generic answer, finds extensions of any length:

```
find . -type f | sed 's/^.*\.\([^.]*\)$/\1/'
```

I then use the following command to get a list of extensions in a dir:

```
find . -type f | sed 's/^.*\.\([^.]*\)$/\1/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cut like this :

```
for file in /a/dir/*/dir/* ; do
  echo \`echo $file | cut -d"." -f 1` >> textfile;
done
```

It will only work if you don't have any file or directories with a "." in the name

Answer (score 0):

You have given an explicit definition for extensions,
But, the tags `linux` and `bash-scripting` suggest a unix environment.
Unless you are doing this with Cygwin on Windows.
These points may not matter in that case...

- Be sure that you do not have numbers in your 'extension' (like `md5`)
- Also, what about extensions with less than 3 characters? (`script.sh`)
- What about extensions with upper case characters?

Comment: I match with my ls very specific files, a base name plus 4x an extension of 3 lowercase characters

Comment: @Peter, in which case, Russell's answer would have sufficed. ok.