# Shell command to remove files extension

Tags: unix, bash, shell, terminal

I have a directory with automatically generated files that all end with the .sample extension.
I would like to have a way to remove the .sample extension from them all in one terminal command.

I tried this:

```
mv ./{$1}*.sample ./$1
```

But it doesn't work because I'm definitely placing the {$1} in the wrong place or way. Can anyone point to the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/44854/linux-how-to-change-the-extension-of-a-bunch-of-files

Answer (score -3, accepted):

One of the many way to do that:

```
for i in *.sample; do NEWNAME=`echo "$i" | sed 's/\.sample//'`; mv "$i" "$NEWNAME"; done
```

Comment: basename is more appropriate; besides your code is wrong: it will croak on filenames with space

Comment: Corrected for space problem

Comment: This has a few other pathological problems as well. Consider what happens if a file is named '*.sample' or 'foo.sample.sample'. See Mark Drayton's solution.

Comment: It fails for file names with multiple spaces, e.g. `a    b.sample`. You should use `echo "$i"` instead of `echo $i`.

Comment: Thanks Cristian, correted. @rogeriopvl you should probably accept markdrayton answer, so that I could suppress my not so good solution.

Answer (score 19):

```
$ touch {a,b,c,"white space"}.sample

$ ls *.sample
a.sample        c.sample
b.sample        white space.sample

$ for SAMPLE in *.sample; do mv -v "$SAMPLE" "${SAMPLE%.sample}"; done
a.sample -> a
b.sample -> b
c.sample -> c
white space.sample -> white space
```

**Edit**: Also see `${parameter#word}`, which deletes `word` from the front of `parameter`:

```
$ FILENAME=140909_stats_report.txt
$ echo "${FILENAME#140909_}"
stats_report.txt
```

I remember which of these I need from the positions of the `#` and `%` keys on my (UK) keyboard: `#` is left of `%` so matches on the left. Before I noticed that I had to check the man page *every* time :~)

These expansions also support shell wildcards:

```
$ echo "${FILENAME%.*}"
140909_stats_report
```

The `#` and `%` forms match the shortest expansion of `word`. You can use `##` or `%%` for the longest match. E.g.:

```
$ FILENAME=140909_stats_report.txt
$ echo "${FILENAME#*_}"  # match as little as possible
stats_report.txt
$ echo "${FILENAME##*_}" # match as much as possible
report.txt
```

It's worth getting to grips with these expansions. There's several more, including (somewhat cranky) regex support, substrings and ways to set defaults or get variable lengths. [Man bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), of course.

Comment: +1 - using the bash parameter substitution is the best solution. No unnecessary processes are spawned and the result is very clean.

Answer (score 6):

```
for n in *.sample ; do mv "$n" "$(basename "$n" .sample)" ; done
```

Answer (score 5):

The `rename` command accepts Perl expressions:

```
rename 's/\.sample$//' *.sample
```

Example:

```
$ ls *sample*
file0.sample  file2.sample  foo.sample.sample
file1.sample  file3.sample  with space.sample
$ rename 's/\.sample$//' *.sample
$ ls *sample*
foo.sample
```

On my Ubuntu system, `rename` is symlinked to the `prename` script from the `perl` package.

Answer (score 1):

```
rename '.sample' '' *.sample
```

On Fedora, the `rename` command is included in the *util-linux-ng* package.