# Batch rename files that end in a dot

Tags: bash, rename

I have a large unix fileserver, with a single large SMB share.  It serves to Mac, Linux and windows clients.  A large portion of the files on this box have been migrated there from a Mac Xserve.  One of the ways the share is backed up is via a Windows box.  That particular backup software fails if there are characters it doesn't like in the filenames.

I've managed to fix most of the filename issues but am struggling with files that end in a dot.  For example:

- `filename.`
- `newfile.txt.`
- `stupid old file.`

I am trying to find some way to batch rename all the files that end in a dot to the same name without the dot.  So `filename.` becomes `filename`

```
find . -name "*."
```

works to find the files.  I've tried piping it through sed:

```
find . -name "*." | sed 's/.$//'
```

which does the job in the console but doesn't actually rename the files.  That's the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](http://serverfault.com/a/64832/1293) regarding the `rename` command which will do what you need. Note that there's another `rename` command which uses different syntax, but it will do what you need, too.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for the response.  I intended. and neglected, to mention in the question, but I can't get rename to deal with the trailing dot I'm having a hard time understanding the way it deals with wildcards.

Comment: See [Is there a linux command like mv but with regex?](http://superuser.com/questions/70217/is-there-a-linux-command-like-mv-but-with-regex).

Comment: @user3408072 Looks like you're new to serverfault. Please remember to upvote answers you like and to accept the answer that you think works best

Answer (score 4):

If you have the Perl script version of `rename` (called either `rename` or `prename`):

```
rename 's/\.$//' *.
```

or the util-linux version (called either `rename` or `rename-ul`):

```
 rename . '' *.
```

If you run the command without arguments and get something similar to:

> Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]

then it's the Perl script version.

Something like:

> rename.ul: not enough arguments
>
> Usage:
>    rename.ul [options] expression replacement file...
>
> Options:  -v, --verbose    explain what is being done  -V, --version
>   output version information and exit  -h, --help       display this
>   help and exit

means it's the util-linux version.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about rename. Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should do the job:

`find . -type f -name '*\.' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${$1%.}"' _ {} \;`

This limits the find to only files with a period at the end (otherwise it matches the current working directory, '.'), and then executes the quoted shell snippet (`mv "$1" "${$1%.}"`) for each filename it finds.  Within the shell snippet it uses bash parameter expansion and substitution to remove the trailing '.'.   The other line noise at the end is required for the find -exec: `{}` is the matched text from the find, `\;` is required to end the exec string, and I believe the `_` tells the exec to pass {} in as a parameter (`$1`) to the `sh` command.  To be honest, this specific usage of -exec is new to me, I found it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35922/how-to-change-extension-of-multiple-files-from-command-line).

The bash substitution bit is pretty straight forward, and I use this quite often for renaming files, e.g. `FILENAME=foo.JPG; mv ${FILENAME} ${FILENAME%.JPG}.jpg` will remove the '.JPG' from FILENAME and replace it with '.jpg'

If you still want to use sed rather than bash expansion, this looks like it'd do the job:

```
find . -type f -name '*\.' -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(echo {} | sed s/\.$// )"' \;
```

I first tried to solve this without causing `-exec` to invoke `sh -c`, but that didn't like expanding {} out while attempting to do the sed (or with the bash substitution example earlier).

Also note that you have to put " " around either the filenames you're expanding (e.g., {} or $1, depending on the example), as your sample files have spaces in them. This may still break depending on what special characters are in your file (e.g., a " in the filename will cause problems).

Comment: I couldn't get the first example with the shell expansion/substitution to work.  Kept getting  `_: ${$1%.}: bad substitution`   Played around a bit and just couldn't make it work, but the sed version worked great. Something weird with bash on this box, the example from DouglasDD that worked had to be tweaked a bit too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should `sh` from the first command be replaced with `bash` because `${$1%.}` is Bash specific as far as I know?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: That might be it. I pulled my example from the link I referred to on askubuntu.com, and I tested on ubuntu. Looks like dash is sufficiently similar to bash in this case, but it might not be on other systems

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hacky but should work:

If you want to rename both files AND directories with trailing dots:

```
    find . -name "*." -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 my_rename.sh
```

OR if you want to rename only the files:

```
    find . -name "*." -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 my_rename.sh
```

Where `my_rename.sh` script is just:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv "$1" "${1%%.}"
```

(Also don't forget to make the script executable:  `chmod +x my_rename.sh`)2

Comment: This gave me find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
mv: target `' is not a directory: No such file or directory  When I changed it to  'find . -type f -name '*.' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 ./my_rename.sh' That worked.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit about my [] syntax shortcut for  `-type f` being optional depending on whether or not you wanted to hit only files, or include dirs as well.